# Refuse Postgresql Connection

Tags: iptables, postgresql

I have an idea to only allow my computer to access the POSTGRES. What is the best way to do it?

- Using IPTABLES to Drop INPUT connections to Postgresql PORT ?
- Using Postgresql File Configuration to allow only locahost connections?

Answer (score 1):

The following pg_hba.conf allows local and specified Ip have privilege login， but reject others。

```
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     trust

host    testdb          testuser      192.168.1.1/32             md5

host    all             all           0.0.0.0/0                 reject
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1, ::1'` in `postgresql.conf`.

If you're on an older computer or don't want to allow IPv6 connections, leave out the `, ::1`.

This will cause PostgreSQL to not even listen for connections from elsewhere.

You can *also* configure `pg_hba.conf` to deny authentication on such connections as the other answer here shows, but it's better to just not accept them in the first place.